# Сборка Boost - не может найти файл corecrt.h

Tags: c++, windows, boost, build

Нужно срочно собрать Boost 1_62_0 на Windows 7 x64 SP1. Нет файла corecrt.h. Такого файла на компьютере нет, где его взять? Почему его не положили в комплект с Boost?

Comment: а как именно собираете? может быть просто забыли выполнить какой-то базовый шаг?

Comment: Нет. Требует Windows 10 SDK. Не хочу с ним связываться принципиально, нужно другое решение. Значит, другая версия Boost...

Comment: можно перейти на линукс. Тут windows sdk не нужно.

Comment: Нет. Я сейчас подтверджу, что это действительно ответ, и напишу его. Уже стоят два Windows SDK(8 и 8.1), третий не нужен. Просто нужно знать, какая версия Boost требует Windows SDK 8.1. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Цитата с Хабрахабра:

> «Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h'» — ищете файл поиском, скорее
>   всего он тут: ProgramFiles(x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt и добавляете директорию в
>   $IncludePath, либо поступаете грубо и копируете все *.h файлы
>   куда-нибудь на видное место, например в Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\VC\include.

Этот вопрос решён.

Comment: Мне кажется что как работать с "библиотечными" хедер файлами - это не тот вопрос которым нужно заполнять базу знаний. Понятно что нужно проверить наличие на компе хедера, если его нету - скачать в нете. Если нету в нете - то всё.